# My professor never answered my email. What should I do?

Tags: professorship

I'm having trouble submitting an assignment into turnit in and my professor never replied back to my email. The assignment had 3 different parts to it and I was only able to submit one of the parts because I tried to submit them separately instead of together. I asked my professor if I could just email him the other 2 parts of the assignment and he never answered back. I emailed him 4 days ago.

Answer (score 3):

You can 1) send a reminder, 2) stop by his office in person and ask, or 3) ask him after a lecture.

If it's urgent I'd do #2, otherwise it's up to you.

Comment: Or (5) contact his secretary if he has one.